# How to save line breaks after parsing?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

anglesharp - 0.9.11

On the page in the browser, the text is displayed as:
String_1.
String_2.
String_3.
String_4.

Parsing result:
 String_1.String_2.String_3.String_4.

Page layout:

```
<div class="adv-point view-adv-point"><span>String_1. <br><br>String_2.<br>String_3.<br>String_4.</span></div>
```

I use code to parse:

```
      var text = document.QuerySelectorAll("div:nth-child(4) >div:nth-child(3) > div.adv-point.view-adv-point"); 
  text = items[0].TextContent.Trim();
```

**Question**
How to make the result of parsing with line breaks?

In other words, the result of the parsing should be:
  String_1.
String_2.
String_3.
String_4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you use innerText here then it will work fine for you. Here is the code

```
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("div:nth-child(4) >div:nth-child(3) > div.adv-point.view-adv-point");

 console.log(x[0].innerText);
```

Comment: I use `anglesharp - 0.9.11y.
Is your offer only for `anglesharp - 0.10.11`?

Comment: ok for angleSharp 0.9.11 you can use this:


                var text = document.QuerySelectorAll(".adv-point.view-adv-point > span");

                Console.WriteLine(text[0].InnerHtml.Replace("<br>", "\n")); 
Let me know if it helps

Comment: Works.
Strange.
I send the data to the database of MS Access through DAO.
In a variable, the data is stored correctly (by a column), and in the database it appears in one line.
You do not know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
var text=document.querySelectorAll(".view-adv-point span")[0].innerText;
```

If you log/alert text, you will see that the line break is present.

If you want to replace `<br>` with `\n`, then you can do this-

```
var text=document.querySelectorAll(".view-adv-point span")[0].innerHTML;
text = text.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
```

But i believe this will return the same value as the first approach